# Extracting information in Excel spreadsheet between specified date ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a master spreadsheet of data that includes the following fields: date, name of worker, amount paid. The spreadsheet is sorted by date. It looks something like this:

01/01/2014 ... John ... $25
01/05/2014 ... Jane ... $36
01/07/2014 ... Jane ... $5
01/09/2014 ... John ... $10

I want to be able to do two things on a new sheet:

1. In each row, I fill in a start and end date, and then a formula computes the total amount of money paid to all of the workers in the time between those two dates. That is, I want to fill in manually

01/01/2014 ... 01/06/2014
01/07/2014 ... 01/10/2014

then have my sheet compute a third column, to get:

01/01/2014 ... 01/06/2014 ... $61
01/07/2014 ... 01/10/2014 ... $15

2. Same as #1, but now I only want the amounts that paid to John by time period.

How can I do this? (I realize Excel is probably not the cleanest way to organize the data, but my boss is insisting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIFS`.

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,">="&A5, A1:A3,"<="&B5)
```

Where B1:B3 is the amount paid per date, A1:A3 is the corresponding payment date, A5 is the start date and B5 the end date. You can change the operators if you need.

Comment: You can also add a third criteria to only sum for a certain name